# Fast way to load over a billion rows into Oracle from text files

Tags: oracle, import, toad

I have approximately 20 text files of data all in the same format and all tab delimited. These files are hundreds of megabytes each and all together I am expecting there to be about 1.2 billion rows of data.

My question - what is the best (and fastest) way to load these into an Oracle table? I attempted to load them via the built in import feature in TOAD, but that was only doing about 7,500 records a minute. At that rate, I'd be waiting a very long time for the import to complete.

I have no problem kicking off the process once for each input file, but I need a way or ideas on how to import these quickly.

Comment: The 7,500 records/min you're hitting is likely because the IO is bottlenecking the import, as it tries to write the logs.

Comment: Try the provided command-line import tools like sqlloader.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have the ability to copy these files to the database server, the most efficient approach should be to use [external tables](http://www.packtpub.com/article/external-tables-oracle-10g-11g-database-part1).  You'd then just need to fire up a `SELECT` statement to load the data.

Comment: +1 I use this concept all the time and I strongly recommend trying this.